# Why does this list comprehension return an Array{Any,1} instead of an Array{Symbol,1}?

Tags: arrays, type-inference, julia

When I try to create an `Array` with a list comprehension, it results in an `Array{Any, 1}` even if I encode all the elements to "symbol":

```
julia> u_col_names=[symbol("user_id"), symbol("age"), symbol("sex"), symbol("occupation"), symbol("zip_code")]
5-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :user_id   
 :age       
 :sex       
 :occupation
 :zip_code 

julia> col_names=["user_id", "age", "sex", "occupation", "zip_code"]
5-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "user_id"   
 "age"       
 "sex"       
 "occupation"
 "zip_code"  

julia> u_col_names=[symbol(col_names[i]) for i in 1:size(col_names)[1]]
5-element Array{Any,1}:
 :user_id   
 :age       
 :sex       
 :occupation
 :zip_code
```

Why does that last list comprehension return an `Array{Any, 1}` instead of an `Array{Symbol, 1}`?
Note that the following *does* return an `Array{Symbol, 1}`:

```
julia> u_col_names=[symbol("col_names$i") for i in 1:size(col_names)[1]]
5-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :col_names1
 :col_names2
 :col_names3
 :col_names4
 :col_names5
```

Interestingly, so does the following:

```
julia> col_names[1]
"user_id"

julia> symbol(col_names[1])
:user_id

julia> [symbol(col_names[1]), symbol(col_names[2])]
2-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :user_id
 :age
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4430) in the issue tracker of the [`JuliaLang/julia` repo on GitHub](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia), the problem seems to stem from a deficiency of Julia's type-inference system. Jeff Bezanson (one of the Julia writers and maintainers) left a [relevant comment](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/524#issuecomment-4329053) in [another discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/524):

> This behavior is actually expected at the moment. Since [`col_names`] is global, it might change anywhere so we can't assume we know its type. This is overly pessimistic, but it's hard to come up with a rule that would let us do better.

Surprisingly, perhaps ([as observed by John Myles White](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4430#issuecomment-25664147)), the type is correctly inferred if those operations are carried out inside a function:

```
julia> function fun()
         col_names=["user_id", "age", "sex", "occupation", "zip_code"]
         return u_col_names=[symbol(item) for item in col_names]
       end
fun (generic function with 1 method)

julia> fun()
5-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :user_id   
 :age       
 :sex       
 :occupation
 :zip_code
```

As an alternative to your list comprehension, you can use `map(symbol, <Array{T,1}>)`, which *does* return an `Array{Symbol,1}`, even at the global scope:

```
julia> col_names=["user_id", "age", "sex", "occupation", "zip_code"]
5-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "user_id"   
 "age"       
 "sex"       
 "occupation"
 "zip_code"  

julia> map(symbol, col_names)
5-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :user_id   
 :age       
 :sex       
 :occupation
 :zip_code
```

Comment: The general principle is that inside functions, the compiler knows "everything": the types of the inputs and the transformations that will be applied. Consequently it can specialize more aggressively.

Comment: @tholy Thanks for your comment. Can you think of any recommended reading about that?